# How can I get multiple icon types on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, r-sf

Hopefully this is a very simple solution. I'm completely new to R Studio and don't even completely understand what code I DO have so far. So please let me know if I need to give more info.

I'm mapping locational data for different plant species, coloring them by decade. I also need to put triangles for plants in an herbarium and circles for the ones observed in the wild. This is what I have so far, along with the image it produces.

In my data, I have a column titled "basisOfRecord" which has the two categories of either human observation or preserved specimen. How would I change my code to assign the map icons? I kind of had this project thrown at me and have been messily googling without a foundation in R or even coding in general, so I'm sorry if my script is really messy.

Here is a link to the map data - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/v2v8x3zy4uhlw3mtan28l/h?rlkey=60g8s28z1mix9co2podjkb16p&dl=0

And here is a link to the CSV - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9t7qpxo1113uban1qpsib/americanus.csv?rlkey=nguai55lmlsc23i48h1j2zeee&dl=0

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(viridis)
library(sf) 


americanus <- read.csv("C:/Users/MayeJ/Documents/Map Data/GBIF/Americanus/americanus.csv")  

month <- 1  
day <- 1
americanus$TrueDate <- as.Date(paste(americanus$TrueDate, month, day, sep = "-"))
print(americanus$TrueDate)

americanus <- americanus[complete.cases(americanus$decimalLatitude, americanus$decimalLongitude), ]

obs.year = lubridate::year(americanus$TrueDate) 
decade.cha = as.character(floor(obs.year / 10) * 10) 
decade = (floor(obs.year / 10) * 10)
americanus <- st_as_sf(americanus, coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs = 4326)

crs = "WGS84"
agr = "constant"
remove = F



class(americanus)


north.america.bound <- st_read("/Users/MayeJ/Documents/Map Data/NA_PoliticalDivisions/NA_PoliticalDivisions/data/bound_l/boundary_l_v2.shp")



americanus.map <- ggplot(data = north.america.bound) + 

  theme_bw() + 
  geom_sf(fill = "gray90", color = "black") + 
  geom_sf(data = americanus, 
          size = 3, 
          shape = 21, 
          alpha = 0.7, 
          aes(fill = decade.cha)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "B", discrete = T, direction = 1) +

  coord_sf(xlim = c(-3235000, 3062000),
           ylim = c(-900000, 4007000)) 


americanus.map



ggsave(plot = americanus.map,
       "C:/Users/MayeJ/Documents/Map Data/GBIF/Americanus/americanusmap.jpg",
       device = "jpg", dpi = 300, units = "in",
       width = 10, height = 7.5)
```

[Here is the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEdWD.jpg)

I've tried looking for examples of maps that use ggplots and sf, to see if they use more than one symbol at a time, but haven't found anything yet. I just don't have any kind of formatting intuition with coding, so I wouldn't even know where to start in experimenting.

Comment: To get different shapes you have to map your variable (`basisOfRecord`??) on the `shape` aes, e.g. try `geom_sf(data = americanus, aes(fill = decade.cha, shape = basisOfRecord), size = 3, alpha = 0.7)` and set your desired shapes using e.g. `scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24))` in case of two categories.

Comment: @stefan I sort of got it to work? Now all the color is gone from the map. 
 `geom_sf(data = americanus,
        aes(fill = decade.cha, 
        shape = basisOfRecord), 
        size = 3, alpha = 0.7)
scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) scale_fill_viridis(option = "B", discrete = T, direction = 1) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-3235000, 3062000),
           ylim = c(-900000, 4007000))`  I wish I could attach the picture to this reply. But it's all black and white with little X's and black circles now. (sorry, I have no idea how to format in comments)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your dataset `americanus` best shared via `dput()`, e.g. run `dput(americanus[1:10,])` and copy the output into your post? This way we can run your code and figure out a solution. (The shapefile is probably from this site: https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4fb555ebe4b04cb937751db9)

Comment: @stefan I've edited the post to include links to download the CSV (it's not very big) and the map data, you are correct about where I got it.  There's a link showing the map output at the end of my post. Does that cover everything? Thank you so much for helping figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `basisOfRecord` column has six categories. Four are simply different versions of `PreservedSpecimen` (e.g. there is also `"preservedspecimen"`), then there is a `"HumanObservation"` and the last one is called `"voucher"`. Hence, when providing only two values for shape (as I suggested in the comment) you will get an error while when not including `scale_shape_manual` you get the first six default shapes which support only the `color` aes but not `fill`.

In the code below I recoded the four variants of `"PreservedSpecimen"` as one  category `"PreservedSpecimen"` and added another shape value for `"voucher"`. However, there was still an issue with fill colors not showing up in the legend which I fixed using `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))`. Additionally I simplified your code a bit, especially the computation of the decades and finally I put the legend at the bottom.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

americanus <- read.csv("americanus.csv")
americanus <- americanus[c("TrueDate","decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude", "basisOfRecord")]

americanus$decade.cha <- factor(10 * americanus$TrueDate %/% 10)

americanus <- americanus[complete.cases(americanus$decimalLatitude, americanus$decimalLongitude), ]

americanus <- st_as_sf(americanus, coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs = 4326)

north.america.bound <- st_read("PoliticalBoundaries_Shapefiles/NA_PoliticalDivisions/data/bound_l/boundary_l_v2.shp")

americanus$basisOfRecord[grepl("^(P|p)reserve", americanus$basisOfRecord)] <- "PreservedSpecimen"
ggplot(north.america.bound) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gray90", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(
    data = americanus,
    aes(fill = decade.cha, shape = basisOfRecord),
    size = 3,
    alpha = 0.7
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24, 22)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "B", direction = 1) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-3235000, 3062000),
    ylim = c(-900000, 4007000)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "vertical") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO SO much. This is way more than I ever expected to get! To confirm for my future plant species in using this as a template of sorts: I need to definitely make sure the basisOfRecord column is formatted consistently. Your code is so much more streamlined than mine was as well. Thank you again, this has been a huge help and lesson for me.